# checkinstall failing to install debian package

Tags: package-management, checkinstall

I'm trying to install sip for pyqt and trying to get checkinstall to work. But it keeps saying

```
    Installing Debian package... FAILED!
```

This is what's in the log file:

```
    (Reading database ... 191312 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../sip_4.16.3-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking sip (4.16.3-1) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /home/user/sip-4.16.3/sip_4.16.3-1_amd64.deb (--install):
    trying to overwrite '/usr/include/python2.7/sip.h', which is also in package python-sip-dev 4.15.5-1build1
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing: /home/user/sip-4.16.3/sip_4.16.3-1_amd64.deb
```

Anyone know how I can fix this and get it to work? I can't find anything on what to do to fix this.. It looks like sip was installed successfully - as I can check the version number.

There also seems to be a deb file in the sip-4.16.3 folder. But when I try to install or remove, I get

```
    dpkg: error processing archive sip_4.16.3-1_amd64.deb (--install):
    trying to overwrite '/usr/include/python2.7/sip.h', which is also in package python-sip-dev 4.15.5-1build1
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing: sip_4.16.3-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have SIP installed.

Your error message says that the file `/usr/include/python2.7/sip.h` already exists, and is part of the `python-sip-dev` file.

You can fix this in two ways:

1. Uninstall `python-sip-dev` using `sudo apt-get uninstall`.
2. Do nothing.